# EntityFramework 4.1 with DbContext code that should be put in Repository Save Method to Save and Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a simple `EntityFramework 4.1` data access with DbContext and I have User Table which mapped to Users now I'm making the UsersRepository and I have this method:

```
public bool Save(Users entity)
{
    ///What should i put here to Save entity or update Same time ?
}
```

I wonder what should I put there to save entity if its new and update if its not, taking consideration that entity might not be attached to the context etc.

**Note:-** I don't want to make a property to expose the ObjectContext from the `DbContext`, as I used to do that expose the objectContext in order to attach directly and test if object is attached , I don't want to do this as I think this not best practice as DbContext should replace all that.

Comment: Could you please expand a little on your note regarding the ObjectContext and what your concerns / goals are for that?

Answer (score 1):

One simple pattern that can work for Insert or Update is to assume that a primary key of zero means that the entity is new and should be added, otherwise it is existing and should be updated. For example:

```
public void Save(Users entity) 
{ 
    context.Entry(entity).State = entity.Id == 0
        ? EntityState.Added
        : EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx for more details.

Comment: what about unattached entities ?

Comment: Setting the State property to Modified will attach the entity if it is not already attached and then change its state to Modified. Likewise, setting the State to Added will add the entity if needed.

Answer (score -1):

`DbContext.SaveChanges();`

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx)